# how to format attributes, prefixes, and tags using xml.etree.ElementTree Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to create a python script that will create a schema to then fill data based on an existing reference.

This is what I need to create:

```
<srp:root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

this is what I have:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import *
from xml.dom import minidom

def prettify(elem):
    rough_string = tostring(elem, "utf-8")
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")

ns = { "SOAP-ENV": "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", 
    "SOAP-ENC": "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding",
    "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "srp": "http://www.-redacted-standards.org/Schemas/MSRP.xsd"}

def gen():
    root = Element(QName(ns["xsi"],'root'))
    print(prettify(root))
gen()
```

which gives me:

> <xsi:root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

how do I fix it so that the front matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact result that you ask for is incomplete, but with a few edits to the `gen()` function, it is possible to generate well-formed output.

The root element should be bound to the `http://www.-redacted-standards.org/Schemas/MSRP.xsd` namespace (`srp` prefix). In order to generate the `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declaration, the namespace must be used in the XML document.

```
def gen():
    root = Element(QName(ns["srp"], 'root'))
    root.set(QName(ns["xsi"], "schemaLocation"), "whatever") # Add xsi:schemaLocation attribute
    
    register_namespace("srp", ns["srp"])                     # Needed to get 'srp' instead of 'ns0'
    
    print(prettify(root))
```

Result (linebreaks added for readability):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<srp:root xmlns:srp="http://www.-redacted-standards.org/Schemas/MSRP.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="whatever"/>
```